# Bind9 - Permission issue

Tags: networking, permissions, 17.10, dns

I had BIND9 installed and working ok. I wanted to output the logs for parsing into MUNIN. 
I had the system working fine, and had the log files generating in /var/cache/bind/ with ownership as root:bind and permissions set as 0644.

However upon reboot BIND9 is no longer started, and an excerpt from the /var/log/syslog shows this:

```
Mar 14 20:45:57 minecraftsvr named[867]: automatic empty zone: 64.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 14 20:45:57 minecraftsvr named[867]: automatic empty zone: 65.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 14 20:45:57 minecraftsvr named[867]: isc_stdio_open '/var/cache/bind/debug.log' failed: permission denied
Mar 14 20:45:57 minecraftsvr named[867]: automatic empty zone: 66.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 14 20:45:57 minecraftsvr named[867]: automatic empty zone: 67.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
```

If I start BIND9 manually it starts, however the above error is still shown.

Any ideas why it stops BIND9 from starting automatically, yet starts manually?

`/etc/Apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named`:

```
  # /etc/bind should be read-only for bind
  # /var/lib/bind is for dynamically updated zone (and journal) files.
  # /var/cache/bind is for slave/stub data, since we're not the origin of it.
  # See /usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian.gz
  /etc/bind/** r,
  /var/lib/bind/** rw,
  /var/lib/bind/ rw,
  /var/cache/bind/** lrw,
  /var/cache/bind/ rw,
  /var/log/bind9/** rw,
  /var/log/bind/ rw,
```

Thanks
Tom

Comment: what permissions does /var/cache/bind/debug.log have and under which user/group do you run bind9?

Comment: Hi, having had a look its running as root :-(. How can I modify it to run as the user bind/group bind as obviously I dont want to really run it as root. Further, I tried changing the owner of the /var/cache/bind.log debug.log and query.log as root:root with no success either.